# From user perspective providing label in html document is good or not?

Tags: html, input, label

Should i provide label for every field or for specific fields only?
I have tried with this one :

```
<label for="name">Name</label> 
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required />
```

Is it a good practice or not ?

Comment: Labels should be provided for input elements like select, radio button,checkboxes and all type of input types like text,number,....https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element    ..And for accessibility it is mandate to have labels with for attribute..hope that provides some insight..

Comment: Also, a note: "Placeholder" is not meant to be used like this. Many use it like this, me included, but placeholder is really meant for an example of proper input, so in this case, `Ex: John Smith` would be better than `Your name`.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended by [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form#The_%3Clabel%3E_element) if you want to make accessible forms.

> The  element is the formal way to define a label for an HTML
>   form widget. This is the most important element if you want to build
>   accessible forms.

Otherwise you can find the W3 official documentation [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element).